# Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default

Tags: python, r, csv, twitter, word-cloud

I'm analyzing 500 tweets for to make a wordcloud in R. I use tweepy to retrieve the tweets of a particular topic and put them in .csv  file which then this R program I've posted below takes in.

```
library(tm)
library(stringr)
library(wordcloud)

tweets <- read.csv("./tweets.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

nohandles <- str_replace_all(tweets$text, "@\\w+", "")

wordCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(nohandles))
wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, removePunctuation)
wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, wordLengths = c(0,Inf))
wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, removeWords, c("amp", "2yo", "3yo", "4yo"))
wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, stripWhitespace)
pal <- brewer.pal(9,"YlGnBu")
pal <- pal[-(1:4)]
set.seed(123)
wordcloud(words = wordCorpus, scale=c(5,0.1), max.words=100, random.order=FALSE,
          rot.per=0.35, use.r.layout=FALSE, colors=pal)


tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(wordCorpus)
tdm
```

This is what the terminal outputes:

```
Loading required package: NLP
Loading required package: methods
Loading required package: RColorBrewer
Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
Calls: tm_map -> tm_map.VCorpus -> mclapply -> lapply -> match.fun
Execution halted
```

**This is due to this line in the R script which helps it get large data:**
wordCorpus <- tm_map(wordCorpus, wordLengths = c(0,Inf))

Now this script works just fine for any twitter archive but doesn't for a csv file which I make using Python [python code posted below] (which gets data from twitter, I've havent posted the api code here but that goes without saying and works fine otherwise the csv file with the tweets wouldn't have been created)

```
csvFile = open('tweets.csv', 'a')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
    q="obama",
    rpp=100,
    result_type="recent",
    include_entities=True,
    lang="en").items(500):
        print (tweet.text)
        analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
        print(analysis.sentiment)
        print("")
        csvWriter.writerow([tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
```

Comment: Your code is such that you can easily run it line by line. I think it's a good idea if you do that and tell us the specific line where the error first occurs. That way we can look closely at that one line, rather than trying to delve into your entire script.

Comment: @rosscova added the line which caused the error.

Comment: That makes sense. `tm_map` needs a function to call, but you haven't put one in there (`wordLengths = c(0,Inf)` is not a function). Is `wordLengths` supposed to be an object? A function parameter? What's it supposed to achieve?

Comment: wordlenghts is a function and it supposed to prevent it from getting strings of big length and override the short limit (read it somewhere on SO). Also here's a reference : 
https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/66739_c4422a1761bd4ee0b0bb8821d7780e12.html

Comment: @rosscova You should know : this problem is only on my Exported csv file and not the official twitter archive - I guess there lies the problem. Any ideas why?

Comment: This looks like the line in question in the example, can you see the difference? `tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus, control = list(wordLengths = c(1, Inf)))`

Comment: `tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(wordCorpus, control = list(wordLengths = c(1, Inf)))

tdm`

@rosscova Did this. I'm now getting this error:

`Error in strwidth(words[i], cex = size[i], ...) : invalid 'cex' value
Calls: wordcloud -> strwidth`

Comment: @rosscova never mind, figured it out. The csv file I made had no headers hence didn't work